# Creating Hudson jobs and views from command line

Tags: command-line, hudson, jobs

Can I create Hudson jobs from the command line?? If yes, can views be created the same way??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always create the xml file for the job. The location will be a new folder in the jobs directory. Than you only need to trigger a reload of the config. It should be similar for the views.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the [Hudson Remote API](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Remote+access+API), which include an API to create Jobs.